# How to connect to an smb share?

Tags: windows, smb

I have a smb share set up (the link `smb://a.b.c.d/sharename`) that I am attempting to connect to from Windows.

I'd like to either connect directly using a browser or mount the share to a virtual drive.

The problem is I can't seem to get it to work properly. Can anyone let me know how this works?

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Linux and Unix, including Mac OS X, use forward slashes in address paths, as you show in your example. However, Windows uses back slashes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be seeing the share in the Network neighborhood and be able to use it from there. Just open Windows Explorer and click on Network.

If you cannot see it, then you have a connectivity problem with the sharing computer.

Comment: The problem is that it's inside a corporate network with thousands of nodes, so the sharing is limited in the network folder to only those that are local to my office.  I can still reach the ip address, but I can't connect to it using smb

Comment: So this is on another network segment. Try in the Windows Explorer address bar to use the following syntax: `\\a.b.c.d\sharename`.

Comment: That seemed to work.  Not sure what I was doing wrong before.  Thanks

Comment: Just straight `\\MACNAME` did the trick for me (with File Sharing for that user's account configured under Mac Sys Prefs: Sharing: Options)

Comment: For anyone using Windows 10 post-2020, please keep scrolling to White_King's answer

Comment: Wes Johnson's answer helped me, and I had to put my Mac username and password when it asked for credentials.

Answer (score 19):

1. Open Windows Explorer.
2. In the path bar, write `\\a.b.c.d` (pay attention to the backward slashes).
3. That should create a new entry in "Network" and show its content.
4. Double-click on the share you want, for instance `sharename` in the example of the question.

Comment: This worked when I wanted to connect to my Mac via SMB. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

After the creator's Update in Windows 10, on new Installs Windows disable SMB1 by default in an attempt to stop a virus.

That might be a problem if you want to browse your shares because it will stop you from detecting them, 2 Options:

1. if you want to enable it Open Windows Features either by searching on windows start or:
   **Control Panel** -> **Programs & Features** -> **Turn Windows Features on or off**.

Tick **SMB1.0**/...
And restart

2. Or you can just map a drive to the share: **Win+E [This PC]** -> **Computer Menu** -> **Map network drive**.
   Choose a Drive letter and specify the Share Network Path and Finish.

Comment: This is crucial.

Comment: Not only is this not crucial, enabling SMB 1.0 is outright DANGEROUS. Even single-user home networks could be affected in case the router has not been configured correctly or an untrusted person gains access to your WiFi network (weak password, friends of friends etc.). "SMB is one of the primary attack vectors for intrusion attempts" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block#Security. "Stop using SMB1" https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/stop-using-smb1/ba-p/425858.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to access Mac files from Windows 10. Actually there is a setting in Mac, which shows at what name is this computer visible.

in my case it was `akshay.local`

from Windows, I can just access my mac by putting `\\akshay.local` in the Run Program URL (`Win+R` > `\\machostname.local`)

Be sure that you have already enabled file sharing on your Mac