# Why the Samba shares on Debian became inaccessible after Windows 10 update to 20H2?

Tags: windows-10, debian, samba

I have updated the ****Windows 10**** to version `20H2` and after that all my Samba shares on the **Debian** are became inaccessible.

The `ping` from *Windows 10* to *Debian* is successful. But when I trying in the Windows Explorer enter the path `\\192.168.2.7\space`, where `space` is a share in the Samba, the following message does appear:

[image]

Tried solutions from this post [How to connect to an smb share?](https://superuser.com/q/347492/1266966) but they did not help.

The `SMB File Sharing Support` enabled on the Windows 10:

[image]

NOTE: I can access the Samba shares from Samsung Galaxy as usual, without problem.

Comment: What version of SMB is the (Samba) host configured to use

Comment: What RamHound means is the version of the SMB protocol, not the application version of the Samba software (which is probably one of the 4.x. versions). Newer Windows systems refuse to connect to SMB protocol v1. Windows 10 likes to use SMB v3.1, but will still connect to V2 and V3.0.

Comment: @Ramhound: On the Debian `smbstatus` returns _Samba version 3.5.6_. On the Windows 10 the `SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support` is enabled. This was working before the Windows latest updates and not changed after the updates was installed.

Comment: @Tonny: On my Windows the `SMB 1.0` was enabled and worked for several years without a problem until I updated the system. Do you advise me to install `SMB 3.1`?

Comment: @Jackdaw - It’s installed by default only SMBv1 has to be enabled due to it not being secure.  Samba 3.5.6 isn’t what I am looking for, see Tony’s explanation

Comment: Not saying that this will work for you but I have WAY WAY better success sharing on the windows side and using the Linux side as a client.  The SAMBA permissions don't need to be goofed with this way..   Never fails.. (at least for me) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what caused the problem.

In my case, from some reason after the Windows upgrade to 20H2, the network discovery service was `Turned off`.

Every time when I checked `Turn on network discovery` radio button and pressed <kbd>Save changes</kbd> the dialog was closed without any message, but the service was failed to start.

[image]

I found in the System event log the following message:

> Description: The Remote Access Connection Manager service depends on
> the DNS Client service which failed to start because of the following
> error:  The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled
> or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

As turned out, the `DNS Client` service was disabled for some reason after upgrading the Windows to `20H2`.
So, enabling and [starting the DNS Client service](https://superuser.com/a/1474100/1266966) helped to turn on the network discovery and all `Samba` shares became visible.

***NOTE:***
*There is very useful post [How to fix ‘Windows cannot access computer’ error code 0x80004005](https://www.alphr.com/windows-cannot-access-computer-error-0x80004005/). This post describes several fixes that might be applied to fix the `Windows cannot access ... Error code 0x80004005` issue.*