# Windows 10 can't map network drive of Linux samba server

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu, samba

Samba server version is `Samba version 4.11.6-Ubuntu`.
Windows client version is `20H2` build `19042.1052`

Not sure what happened with the connection as it has worked before. Now I've tried everything and it still doesn't want to connect.

Here is some facts that may help:

- I can connect to the server through samba on my macOS laptop.
- I can ping my server with it's ipv4 `192.168.x.x`
- I've tried both enabling and disabling SMB1.0 in Windows features
- I've tried putting a `min protocol = SMB2` in `smb.conf`
- My Windows client workgroup is `WORKGROUP` and in `smb.conf` I have `workgroup = WORKGROUP`
- I do not have firewall enabled on my samba server (`ufw`)
- Log file of my client in samba `[2021/06/28 08:53:12.829695,  0] ../../source3/smbd/process.c:340(read_packet_remainder) read_fd_with_timeout failed for client 192.168.1.6 read error = NT_STATUS_END_OF_FILE.`
- `net view \\192.168.x.x` returns `System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found.`

Comment: What is status of the **_DNS Client_** service on your Windows?

Comment: It's disabled. Should it be on?

Comment: See answer below. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `DNS Client` service should be running to support the network shares. Enabling the `DNS Client` service and turning on the network discovery will help the `Samba` shares became enabled.

If the `DNS Client` service is disabled any services that explicitly depend on it will fail to start. In your case it's the `Remote Access Connection Manager` service. It depends on the `DNS Client` service and required to support the `Network discovery`.

*A solution of similar problem is described here: [Why the Samba shares on Debian became inaccessible after Windows 10 update to 20H2?](https://superuser.com/q/1644246/1266966)*

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem. My **DNS Client** service was turned off from a host file editing script.